# Getting the first and last elements in a JSON list and finding the time difference

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, nested-lists

I'm trying to pull data from this endpoint: https://developer.keeptruckin.com/reference#get-logs

So far what I've accomplished to do is get the all the status changes for the driver's log and the events associated to those. I now only want to display the first and last event for each and every driver each day and skip all the events in between for each driver, but can't seem to understand how to do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
import csv
import math

url='https://api.keeptruckin.com/v1/logs?start_date=2020-01-20&end_date=2020-02-03'
header={'x-api-key':'API_KEY_HERE','x-time-zone':'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'}
r=requests.get(url,headers=header)
result=r.json()
result = json.loads(r.text)
num_pages=math.ceil((result['pagination']['total'])/100)
for page in range (1,num_pages):
    r=requests.get(url,headers=header, params={'page_no': page,'per_page':'100'})
    result=r.json()
    result = json.loads(r.text)
    csvheader=['First Name','Last Name','Date','Time','Type','Location','Vehicle']
    with open('test.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        ##writer.writerow(csvheader)
        for log in result['logs']:
            username = log['log']['driver']['username']
            first_name=log['log']['driver']['first_name']
            last_name=log['log']['driver']['last_name']
            for vehicle in log['log']['vehicles']:
                number=vehicle['vehicle']['number']
            for event in log['log']['events']:
                start_time = event['event']['start_time']
                date, time = start_time.split('T')
                time1,time2=time.split('-')
                event_type = event['event']['type']
                location = event['event']['location']
                if not location:
                    location = "N/A"
                if (event_type=="on_duty" or event_type=="driving" or event_type=="off_duty"):
                    writer.writerow((first_name, last_name,date, time1, event_type, location, number))
```

After this step what I'm trying to achieve is that once I have the first and last event for each driver, I want to find the time difference between those 2 events and add that in a new column.

Comment: at least include the structure of  JSON you are getting, it's very hard to understand from your code.

Comment: @vkSinha the structure (sample response) of the code is provided in the link I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your string using dateutil.parser, it will give you datetime object.
You can then save all necessary information about events on the list including datetime object, where each entry in the list is a tuple containing all info about events.Then you can sort the list based on datetime object. From the list you can take out first and last events. Difference between two datetime object will give you timedelta, which can be easily converted to seconds.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
for log in result['logs']:
        username = log['log']['driver']['username']
        first_name=log['log']['driver']['first_name']
        last_name=log['log']['driver']['last_name']
        for vehicle in log['log']['vehicles']:
            number=vehicle['vehicle']['number']
        events = []
        for event in log['log']['events']:
            start_time = parse(event['event']['start_time'])
            end_time = parse(event['event']['end_time'])


            location = event['event']['location']
            # add all data as tuple you want to save for event
            events.append((start_time,end_time, location))
        #sort based on first element of tuple -- start_time
        events.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])      
        first_event = events[0]
        last_event = events[-1]
        #time difference in seconds
        time_diff = (first_event[0]-last_event[0]).seconds # first_event[0] -- start time
```